# how to get the text inside <td> using jquery if a <td> contain more than one value

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a table which will create dynamically during a button click

```
<table id="diagnosis" style="display:none">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="diag-%" class="diag" style="width:200px" type="text" name="provider_diagnosis_dtls[#].diagnosis_code" value /> 
         </td>
        <td>
            <input id="desc-%" class="diag_desc" style="width:500px" type="text" name="provider_diagnosis_dtls[#].diagnosis_desc" value /> 
         </td>
        <td>
            <input id="level-%" type="text" name="provider_diagnosis_dtls[#].diagnosis_level" readonly value />
            <input type="hidden" name="provider_diagnosis_dtls.Index" value="%" /> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am able to print the value of 3rd input ie is "level-%"
using below code

```
var table = $("#diagnosis");
table.find('tr').each(function(i, el) {
    var $tds = $(this).find('td');
    if (diagnosis_row != 1) {
        alert($tds.eq(2).find('input').val());
    }
    diagnosis_row++;
});
```

Now i need to get the value of

```
<input type="hidden" name="provider_diagnosis_dtls.Index" value="%" />
```

which coming under the same `<td>` of "level-%" how can I achieve the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Attribute Equals Selector [name=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value exactly equal to a certain value.

```
$tds.eq(2).find('input[type=hidden]').val();
```

OR, [`:eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

> Select the element at index n within the matched set.

```
$tds.eq(2).find('input:eq(1)').val();
```

OR, [`:hidden`](https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/)

```
$tds.eq(2).find(':hidden').val();
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply..its working like a charm..i tried `.find('hidden')` :) but not `(':hidden')`

Answer (score 2):

For this HTML you  can use [:hidden](https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/)

```
$tds.eq(2).find(':hidden').val()
```